# How can i access to LayoutInflater imageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, layout-inflater

This is my Object

```
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fullscreen_preview, container, false);

        ImageView imageViewPreview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_preview);

        Image image = images.get(position);

        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(image.getLarge())
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imageViewPreview);

        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }
```

And this is my onShare function.

public void onShareItem() {
        // Get access to bitmap image from view

```
      ImageView  i = (ImageView) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_fullscreen_preview,null).findViewById(R.id.image_preview);

    //imageViewPreview = (ImageView) viewPager.findViewById(R.id.image_preview);
    // Get access to the URI for the bitmap
    Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(imageViewPreview);
    if (bmpUri != null) {
        // Construct a ShareIntent with link to image
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        // Launch sharing dialog for image
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
    } else {
        // ...sharing failed, handle error
    }
}
```

when i debug app, imageview is null..

I want to share image in R.id.image_preview 
So how can i get access to R.id.image_preview image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a class variable for storing the ImageView, so you can use it everywhere in the class?

```
private ImageView mImageView;

public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fullscreen_preview, container, false);

    mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_preview);
    ...
}

public void onShareItem() {  
    if (mImageView != null) {
         Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(imageViewPreview);
         ...
     }
}
```

Comment: mImageView = (ImageView) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_fullscreen_preview,null).findViewById(R.id.image_preview);


        Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(mImageView); böpUri is null :(